# Select specific html tags from a liste of html tag via a jquery or spath selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

With this html structure :

```
...
<div class="a">April 2018</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) --> 
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="d">...</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="d">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
...
```

I want save in an array the list of the first div elements with the class "c" before the first div element with the class "d". How can I do that via a jquery selector or an xpath selector ? I don't find how do..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `.prevAll()`
2. Use `.eq()` to select the first element with class d then `.prevAll()` to get all previous element with class c

```js
$('.d').eq(0).prevAll('.c').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">April 2018</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) --> 
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="d">...</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="d">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div> <!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prevAll` to find previous div with class `c` before your `d` class.

```js
$('.d:first').prevAll("div.c").each(function (index, element) {
console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">April 2018</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">1.I want get this tag (and its children)</div>
<!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">2.I want get this tag (and its children)</div>
<!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">3.I want get this tag (and its children)</div>
<!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="c">4.I want get this tag (and its children)</div>
<!-- I want get this tag (and its children) -->
<div class="d">...</div>
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="d">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="b">Monday 02</div>
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
<div class="c">...</div>
<!-- I don't want get this tag ! -->
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an option without `jQuery` :

use [querySelector(".d")](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)[0] to get the first `div` with className `d` , and loop through the previous `divs` using [previousSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_previoussibling.asp) until the className is different than `c` then `break;`

```
let wantedDivs = [];
let element = document.querySelectorAll('.d')[0];

while(element = element.previousElementSibling){
    if(element.className != "c")
        break;
    else
        wantedDivs.push(element);
}

console.log(wantedDivs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using $.each for each div

```
   var arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').each(function() {
         if ($(this).hasClass('c')) {
                arr.push($(this).html());
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('d')) {
        return false;
        }
    });
    });
```